# How to show keyboard with numbers and symbols by default - ionic

Tags: android, angular, ionic5

How to show keyboard like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VwpIl.png) by default on **android** ionic5 app?

I've tried `type="number"` but it only allows to input numbers. On ios it shows full keyboard with this type.
By default, I mean to show it immediately after user clicks on the input

Comment: That looks like a regular keyboard whose option is showing the numbers and other special characters. Looking at their docs I do not see anything that seems to imply that you can force a keyboard to have that look.

Answer (score 0):

You need to [use inputmode](https://ionicframework.com/docs/developing/keyboard) and not type as per [the documentation.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/inputmode)

Comment: Already tried this, shows only the keyboard with numbers and , . - characters and I need a full keyboard, as shown in the attached screenshot

Comment: Would be useful to mention that in "things you've already tried" then. Also where does the screenshot come from?

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/VwpIl.png - just a regular numbers/symbols android keyboard

Answer (score 0):

Try this type of input, it works for me

```
<ion-input type="text"></ion-input>
```

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't.  In face, you can't even be sure the keyboard has a screen like that on Android.  On Android, the keyboard is a separate app, and not all OEMs use the same one (and the user can also switch it out themselves).  You can set the input type as a hint for what it should display-  but it can ignore that hint.  And the hints are very generic-  text, email, number, password, things like that.  There's no hint that says "symbols screen" and not every keyboard has a screen line that. And I don't know of any hint that commonly maps to that either.